# handlebars.js 'else' not working as expected

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

http://jsfiddle.net/3U4uh/28/ working code here, how can I add and 'if' helper to check if there is data inside?

I have tried to do this:

```
      <script id="shoe-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
                {{#if people}}
                    <li class="shoes">
                        <p>{{name}}</p>
                    </li>
                {{/if}}
  </script>
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: `{{#if people.length !== 0}}`?

Comment: that doesn't seem to work, all i need for now is to check if there is data or not using the 'if' helper

Comment: As an aside, I'd recommend against storing your template `<script>` inside your content (i.e. `<ul><script>...</script></ul>`), that makes it too easy to nuke your `<script>` while manipulating your `<ul>`. And you can import external JavaScript and CSS files at jsfiddle using the *External Resources* panel in the sidebar.

Comment: Hi thanks for your tip, for simplicity I did like this, however I am separating data in a js file, templates in a php file, the script in a js file so that the HTML is cleaner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop through something and display a "nothing there" message if the list is empty, then use `{{#each}}` and `{{else}}`:

```
{{#each array}}
    <li class="shoes">
        <p><b>{{name}}</b></p>
    </li>
{{else}}
    <li>
        <p><b>Nothing there</b></p>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

That works equally well if `array` is empty or not defined at all.

If you just want to test if an array is present and contains something, then a simple `{{#if}}` should do the trick:

```
{{#if array}}
    The array has things in it.
{{else}}
    The array is empty or not defined at all.
{{/if}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZmXzN/